# Is there a way to get information about the previous iPod song?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, mpmediaitem

I'm trying to store the playhead time of a song (MPMediaItem) before the next song begins to play. How would you do that?

Is there something like `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification` which fires *before* the song changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: When the song changes, set a variable `foo` somewhere to the current time, and set another variable `bar` to the new song's current playback time (usually gonna be `0.0`.) When the song changes again, subtract the value of `foo` from the current time, then add the value of `bar`; the result is the final offset of the song that was just being played.

You'll also have to handle fast forward, rewind, stop, and pause, but you can do that by monitoring the playback state and querying the song's current playback time to keep yourself in sync as needed.

Comment: How would you handle the fast forward, rewind, stop and pause, more specifically?

Comment: Listen for `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`.

Answer (score 1):

I do'nt think, there is such notification(Notify before song change) exist today.
I just find only two notification which can be listen for songs change state.

```
MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification,
MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification,
```

Apple Documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no notification before media item is changed. The best way seems to use a timer to constantly copying the value from media player to a variable to store NSTimeInterval, until media item is changed or media player state is changed.